# how to pass checkbox summation value?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

how to store total value to database? 
here is my javascript:

```
<script>
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){ 
var tot = 0;
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
tot+=parseInt($(this).val());
$('#usertotal').html(tot)
});
});
</script>
```

link which i refer:
http://jsfiddle.net/H4d7W/

Comment: you need an ajax call

Comment: @jhyap: how to do that?